# Phonegap Android app - event when app is transitioned to active/running from stopped

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a way to track (event?) via javascript when an Android Phonegap app is transitioned to active/running having been in the stopped state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pause and resume events that are fired when you put your app in the background and when it comes back out.  Of course, if your app died in the background, you'll be firing resume as well as deviceready when you come back into Cordova.

The docs talk about all the Cordova events here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html